# How can I make a "digital switch"?

Tags: arduino

It would work that way:

- An IR sensor is used as input, if it receives some IR signal, the input is 0.
- If it detects that input, it should output some voltage.
- If it detects that input again, iy should make the output 0.

(Basically, if it detects something on input, it should reverse the current output.)

It's pretty easy to make it using Arduino, but I think it's a waste of hardware. Is there a way to make it using only electrical components?

Comment: Are you familiar with the flip-flop circuit?  Specifically a T type (JK with both inputs shorted together)

Comment: Exactly what sort of IR source and detector?  If you need to select those, then start out by describing you exact application problem.  If you want something like the toggle on-off control on a TV remote, that typically does use a compact MCU for decoding, following a receiver with AGC seeking 38 KHz pulses, and another MCU or fixed equivalent in the remote to encode that.  And respond please by editing your question, not just in comments.

Answer (score -1):

What you are describing can be done with a T flip flop. Every time T and - > are 1 Q becomes Q bar it toggles the value of Q.

Comment: Probably not in practice, as IR detection is a bit less consistent than you are imagining, so this is likely to just annoyingly toggle in a fairly useless fashion.

Comment: Hmm I don't know. I have never built one circuit. I use simulators like fastlab.